# Azure function host won't resolve dependencies

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions, paket

I'm trying to use F# and Paket with Azure Functions. I'm running the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli) so I can run my functions locally, before deploying them to Azure.

The problem is when I run the function, compilation fails with:

```
warning FS211: The search directory 'C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Local\Temp\51f4f9fa-dc47-48b7-a2fa-432b52cf02a9\../packages' could not be found
```

The relevant code looks like:

```
#I "../packages"

#r "FSharp.Data/lib/net40/Fsharp.Data.dll"
#r "WindowsAzure.Storage/lib/net45/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"
#r "System.Net.Http/lib/net46/System.Net.Http.dll"
```

Now, `../packages` is the correct path to Paket dependencies, relative to the .fsx file. This works fine when I run the code interactively in VS Code, but the Azure host seems to be using a strange search directory (which doesn't exist, BTW) rather than using the code directory.

I tried specifying absolute paths like:

```
#r "C:/MY_PATH/packages/FSharp.Data/lib/net40/Fsharp.Data.dll"
#r "C:/MY_PATH/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/lib/net45/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"
#r "C:/MY_PATH/packages/System.Net.Http/lib/net46/System.Net.Http.dll"
```

Doing this let the code compile, but then I got this error when running it:

```
Unable to find assembly 'FSharp.Data, Version=2.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Are you missing a private assembly file?
```

I checked and the `FSharp.Data` assembly is indeed at version 2.3.3.0

Any ideas on how I can get the Azure function host to find and use my dependencies?

Comment: It seems like the Functions teams are now leaning towards pre-compiled functions for F# and C# instead of scripts. We've had more joy with this approach. It should simplify your paket dependency story as you'll just be supplying DLLs. It also makes it pretty easy to debug in VS by starting the project by calling the Functions tooling. Another benefit is a faster startup time for your functions.

Comment: Krzysztof Cieslak has an example of Azure function using Paket for dependency management - I was trying to do this recently and this helped a lot: https://github.com/Krzysztof-Cieslak/AzureFunctionsSamples

Comment: @TomasPetricek I read a blog article of his, but it didn't contain anything for developing locally

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox thanks, I'll give that a try see how it goes

Comment: @Cocowalla The sample worked locally for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working now, as long as I don't specify a search path with `#I`, and include the full relative path for references.

I'm really not sure *why* this is the case though.